# CQ 5.6 Reverse replication: Replication triggered, but no agent found or selected

Tags: aem

I'm trying to write custom file upload component for CQ5.6, but I meet the problem with reverse replication. Node created in Publish instance, but not replicated to Author instance. After replicator call, next line appears in error.log:

```
com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicatorImpl Replication triggered, but no agent found or selected.
```

Replication agents are turned on. In other cases, userforms for example, replication works successfully, so I'm think the problem is somewhere in my code. There is the code I use:

```
Node node = session.getNode(path);
ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
Binary contentValue = valueFactory.createBinary(is);
Node parent = node.addNode(fileName, "nt:unstructured");
parent.setProperty(DELETED, false);
parent.setProperty(DESCRIPTION, description);
Node fileNode = parent.addNode(fileName, "nt:file");
fileNode.addMixin("mix:referenceable");
Node resNode = fileNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
resNode.setProperty(Property.JCR_DATA, contentValue);
Calendar lastModified = Calendar.getInstance();
lastModified.setTimeInMillis(lastModified.getTimeInMillis());
resNode.setProperty(Property.JCR_LAST_MODIFIED, lastModified);
parent.setProperty("cq:distribute", true);
parent.setProperty("cq:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
parent.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", session.getUserID());
session.save();
replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, parent.getPath());
session.logout();
```

What should I do to make reverse replication works for this nodes I create in servlet?

**UPDATE:**
According to Tomek Rękawek answer I updated my code, but problem still not solved. Here is new code:

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
String path = (String) componentContext.getProperties().get(SAVEPATH);
Node node = session.getNode(path);
ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
Binary contentValue = valueFactory.createBinary(is);
Node parent = node.addNode(fileName, "cq:Page");
Node jcrContent = parent.addNode("jcr:content", "cq:PageContent");
jcrContent.setProperty("cq:distribute", true);
jcrContent.setProperty("cq:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
jcrContent.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", session.getUserID());
Node fileNode = jcrContent.addNode(fileName, "nt:file");
fileNode.addMixin("mix:referenceable");
Node resNode = fileNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
resNode.setProperty(Property.JCR_DATA, contentValue);
session.save();
session.logout();
```

Answer (score 5):

Reverse replication is action performed by the author instance, not the publish. Agent responsible for this is *Reverse Replication Agent* on the author. It connects to the publish every 30 seconds and gathers page nodes with `cq:distribute` property set.

In order to reverse replicate the image you need to:

1. Create `cq:Page` node
2. Create `cq:PageContent` node under it and name it `jcr:content`.
3. Create your image node under the `jcr:content` **and save your session** [edited]
4. Set `cq:distribute`, `cq:lastModified` and `cq:lastModifiedBy` properties on the `jcr:content` node.
5. Save the session

Sample method that creates page wrapping input stream and reverse-replicates it:

```
private void reverseReplicateBinary(Session session, String parentPath, String name, InputStream is)
        throws RepositoryException {
    ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
    Node parent = session.getNode(parentPath);

    Node page = JcrUtils.getOrCreateUniqueByPath(parent, name, "cq:Page");
    Node jcrContent = page.addNode(Property.JCR_CONTENT, "cq:PageContent");
    Node file = jcrContent.addNode("file", "nt:file");
    Node resource = file.addNode(Property.JCR_CONTENT, "nt:resource");
    resource.setProperty(Property.JCR_DATA, valueFactory.createBinary(is));
    session.save();

    jcrContent.setProperty("cq:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
    jcrContent.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", session.getUserID());
    jcrContent.setProperty("cq:distribute", false);
    session.save();
}
```

Complete example can be found on [the gist](https://gist.github.com/cqtips/7642439).

That's all. You don't need to call replicator manually, author instance will gather page automatically.

Comment: Could you update your question with new version of the code? Do you have any replication-related messages in publish logs after saving the session?

Comment: I've updated question, sorry that I not done it promptly. No, there isn't any messages related to replication in logs.

Comment: It seems that you have to save your session after creating the page, then add three `cq:...` properties and save the session again. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Tomek Rękawek Is it possibe to write custom reverse replicator which which will gather data from external service (unrelated with cq) ?

Comment: @TomekRękawek I followed these steps and it worked perfectly (previously in AEM6.0). But suddenly setting cq:distribute to true has stopped triggering reverse replication. I'm wondering if the steps are tried to specific version of AEM.  I am using AEM6.1 SP1

Comment: @TomekRękawek According to your code, we have to set distribute to false again to trigger it next time by making it true. This means when ever a page content is changed we need to programmatically change the distribute value to true and then to false for reverse replication to work properly each time. is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

For your replicator object make sure to set the agent ID of "outbox"

```
    AgentIdFilter filter = new AgentIdFilter("outbox");
    ReplicationOptions opts = new ReplicationOptions();
    opts.setFilter(filter);
    replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, parent.getPath(), opts);
```