# ADOBE CQ 5.5 Reverse Replication (Publisher -> Author) triggering by code, but not running at all

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I did quite some research on how to do so, and finally come to this:

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
Node formRootNode = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/usergenerated/content/XXX").adaptTo(Node.class);
String id = incrementId(formRootNode);
Node formNode = formRootNode.addNode("data" + id, "nt:unstructured");
formNode.setProperty("id", id);
formNode.setProperty("name", "John");
session.save();
formNode.setProperty("cq:distribute", true);
formNode.setProperty("cq:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
formNode.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", session.getUserID());
session.save();
```

For the **XXX**, it's type of **cq:Page**. When I try out this code in **Publisher**, new nodes did get inserted into **Publisher** (eg: /content/usergenerated/content/XXX/data1), just that it's not replicated to **Author**.

I have gathered any possible know-hows on how to do this over the Internet:

- http://forums.adobe.com/message/4904901 (main reference, as it was "answered")
- [CQ 5.6 Reverse replication: Replication triggered, but no agent found or selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162289/cq-5-6-reverse-replication-replication-triggered-but-no-agent-found-or-selecte) (secondary reference)
- http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToUseReverseReplication.html (didn't notice any similar outgoing/incoming logs as suggested)

Unfortunately still didn't manage to get it working after studying above advises/examples, anyone could please kindly shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a separate `cq:Page` for each piece of user-generated content.
2. `cq:distribute` property should be set on the `jcr:content` resource.

Example:

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
Node formRootNode = JcrUtil.createPath("/content/usergenerated/content/formPage", true, "sling:Folder", "cq:Page", session, false);
Node formNode = formRootNode.addNode("jcr:content", "cq:PageContent");
formNode.setProperty("name", "John");
session.save();
formNode.setProperty("cq:distribute", true);
formNode.setProperty("cq:lastModified", Calendar.getInstance());
formNode.setProperty("cq:lastModifiedBy", session.getUserID());
session.save();
```

Example uses [`JcrUtil.createPath`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createPath%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Session,%20boolean%29) to create unique node under `/content/usergenerated/content`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for sharing the knowledge, your suggestion works just fine. Appreciate.

Comment: Tomek. Do you know whether this is still valid method in AEM6.3? Also is cq:distibute a Boolean type when saved in the repository or String?